# 3D image alignment: How to extract rotation angles about "static" x,y,z axes from a 3x3 rotation matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am carrying out 3D imaging alignment using (as an overview) the following coding scheme:

```
ref = imref3d(size(img(:,:,:,1)),[0 32] ,[0 32] ,[0 20] );
[optimizer, metric] = imregconfig( 'monomodal');
tform=imregtform(img(:,:,:,2), ref, img(:,:,:,1), ref, 'rigid', optimizer, metric);
transform_mat=tform.T
```

For clarification, the variable `img` is a time series of 3D images (where each 3D image is a stack of 2D cross sections). At different time points, the object I am imaging can move. Thus, the purpose of the above code is to generate a geometric transformation that optimally aligns the second time point of the 3D volume (  `img(:,:,:,2)` ) to a reference image, which is the first time point of the 3D volume ( `img(:,:,:,1)`). The geometric transformation that is finally chosen by the optimization algorithm is output to the object `tform`. `tform` contains a 4x4 matrix as one of its properties (`T`); it is this 4x4 matrix that encodes the translation and rotation information. As you can see from my above code, I stored this 4x4 matrix in the variable `transform_mat`.

After reading through a lot of scattered mathworks documentation, I determined that this `transform_mat` variable (representing an affine **rigid body** transformation matrix) is in a "*post-multiplied*" form, which, as I understand it, just means that it is the transposed version of what one would traditionally see in a linear algebra text book.

For my purposes, **I am interested in extracting specific rotation information** from `transform_mat`. Here is what I have done so far:

```
rot_postmultiply=transform_mat(1:3,1:3); %extracting the elements that encode rotation-related info
rot_premultiply=rot_postmultply'; %transposing
```

Just to quickly interject, I created the premultiplied version of the rotation matrix because I believe that many of the functions that **act on** rotation matrices assume that it is in its premultiplied form.

From this 3x3 rotation matrix, **I want to extract the rotations** (in radians) **about the STATIC x-axis, y-axis, and z-axis of the reference image**. My initial attempt at carrying this out is as follows:

```
eul = rotm2eul(rot_premultiply);
```

The `rotm2eul` function provides me the 3 **Euler Angles** associated with this 3x3 rotation matrix. `eul` is a 1x3 vector and, according to documentation, the "default order for Euler angle rotations is 'ZYX' ". However, I am not certain that *Euler Angles* are actually describing the information I want to extract (i.e. rotations about the static x, y, z axes of the reference image).

I do not have a strong linear algebra/geometric transformation background, but my understanding of Euler Angles is that each rotation that takes place **changes the coordinate system**. For example, after the rotation about the Z axis (the first value in the `eul` vector), we now have **new** X and Y axes (call them X' and Y'). Then the "Y-axis rotation" (the second value in `eul`) is actually the rotation about Y'...*not* Y. Repeat this argument for the final "X-rotation" (which would *really* be about an X'' axis).

If anyone could offer some insight about how to proceed (and if my concerns about Euler Angles are correct), I would greatly appreciate it!

Also, sorry if the word "**static**" is the incorrect terminology. Hopefully, I have provided sufficient context so that no confusion arises.

Comment: so why aren't you using `rotm2axang`?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, all you need is [`rotm2axang`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/robotics/ref/rotm2axang.html) that converts a rotation given as an orthonormal rotation matrix, `rotm`, to the corresponding axis-angle representation, `axang`. The input rotation matrix must be in the premultiply form for rotations.

The output of `rot2axang` is an n-by-4 matrix of n axis-angle rotations. The first three elements of every row specify the rotation axis, and the last element defines the rotation angle (in radians).

If you dont have access to the robotics system toolbox that has that function, consider [this alternative](https://gist.github.com/mithi/796faff6b82f67983d4d3f842bafdf1d) instead.

EDIT:

Rotation of a point in 3D space by an angle `alpha` about an arbitrary axis defined by a line between two points `(x1,y1,z1)` and `(x2,y2,z2)` can be achieved by the following steps:

1. translation so that the rotation axis passes through the origin
2. rotation around x axis so that the rotation axis lies in the xz plane (or projection on the xz plane)
3. rotation around y axis so that the rotation axis lies along the z axis (or projection on the z axis)
4. rotation by `alpha` around the z axis
5. the inverse of step 3
6. the inverse of step 2
7. the inverse of step 1

Are you asking about the angles in steps 2,3?

Otherwise, are you already in the origin for the axis around which you rotate?

If indeed you need the angles in step 2,3 then:

step #1 is done via a the translation matrix T:

```
T =  [ 1    0   0   -x1
      0     1   0   -y1
      0     0   1   -z1
      0     0   0   1  ];
```

Step #2 is done via the following:
Given that `v = (a,b,c)` is the unit vector along the rotation axis, then `d = sqrt(b^2 + c^2)` as the length of the projection onto the yz plane.  Then rotate by the angle between the projection of rotation axis in the yz plane and the z axis given by the dot product of the z component of the unit vector `v` and its yz projection. This angle (`beta`) is determine by: `cos(beta) = dot([0,0,c],[0,b,c]) /(c*d) = c/d , sin(beta) = cross( [0,0,c],[0,b,c]) /(c*d) = b/d`

The rotation matrix Rx is therefor:

```
Rx = [ 1    0     0     0
       0    c/d  -b/d   0
       0    b/d   c/d   0
       0    0     0     1 ] ;
```

Step 3 we rotate  around the y axis so that the rotation axis lies along the positive z axis. Using dot and cross product relationships  the cosine of the angle is `d`, the sine of the angle is `a`. The rotation matrix about the y axis Ry is

```
Ry = [ d    0   -a  0
       0    1   0   0
       a    0   d   0
       0    0   0   1];
```

Last, we rotate around z simply by the angle `alpha`

```
Rz = [ cos(alpha)   sin(alpha)  0   0
      -sin(alpha)   cos(alpha)  0   0
       0            0           1   0
       0            0           0   1 ] ;
```

Comment: Here is my understanding of `rotm2axang` when applied to just one 3x3 premultiplied rotation matrix: I will generate a 1x4 row vector. The first three components (which I will call a,b, c) together form a unit vector. This unit vector represents the axis of rotation. The 4th value in that 1x4 row vector then represents the number of radians rotated about that unit vector axis of rotation. My question is thus "how do I decompose a single rotation about this unit axis of rotation vector into the rotation about the x,y, and z axes of the reference image coordinate system".

Comment: `vrrotmat2vec` also does this. But, once again, I am specifically interested in the question of: "how do I decompose a single rotation about this unit axis of rotation vector into the rotation about the x,y, and z axes of the reference image coordinate system"

Comment: This is mostly a math question at this point, so I may move over to stackexchange, but I did not know whether or not matlab offered a function that could carry out the operation I am interested in.

Comment: but what are the `x,y,z` axes here if not the first three component of that vector? If you rotate  only once in 3D around some arbitrary axis of rotation, this will have a projection on the x,y,z axes given by angles that are defined according to some origin.  I edited my answer with some questions to try and better understand what you want. also, a minimal example would be nice here. after all it is all geometry and trigonometry,  nothing crazy is going on here.

Comment: Perhaps the confusion arises from my understanding of the `rotm2axang` function (as I am really not sure I am grasping your comments in the edit). Let the output of `rotm2axang` be defined by the ordered quadruplet (a,b,c,r). Firstly, sqrt(a^2+b^2+c^2) = 1. `a` is the x component magnitude of this unit vector, `b` is the y component magnitude of this unit vector, and `c` is the z component of this unit vector. Thus, this unit vector is anchored at (0,0,0). The value `r` determines how much every point that comprises the rigid body is rotated about the axis represented by the unit vector.

Comment: Given an arbitrary point in our 3D space (m,n,p), I want to know how I can use the above information encoded in (a,b,c,r) to extract an R_x (rotation about the x axis of the image), R_y (rotation about the y axis of the image), and R_z (rotation about the z axis of the image) matrix that acts on (m,n,p) in the same way our original 3x3 "mixed" rotation matrix does (i.e. `rot_premultiply`)

Comment: I believe that the composition of R_x, R_y, and R_z is non-commutative, so perhaps my overall question is not particularly useful. If this is the case, do you have a suggestion as to how one should best report the information contained within that rotation matrix `rot_premultiply`?

Answer (score 1):

I think the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39128589) should help you out: to decompose a 3D rotation into Cartesian components.